# Proxylist for a list of elements containg groups

Tags: python, list, proxy

Having a list of integers:

```
>>> l = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 6, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0]
```

How could I build a proxy like that behaves like:

```
>>> proxy = Proxy(l)
>>> proxy[0]
0
>>> proxy[1]
0 
>>> proxy[2]
3
>>> proxy[3]
0
>>> proxy[4]
6
>>> proxy[5]
2
>>> proxy[6]
12 
>>> proxy[7]
0
>>> proxy[8]
0
```

The zeros add up to the index. The repeated elements just adds 1, and son on. The repeated elements are added. The result of this sum is the value of the proxy in that index. The proxy internally may be a dict with indexes as integer keys or another list.
The indexes in the proxy are:

```
 index 0 relates to l[0], 
 index 1 relates to l[1], 
 index 2 relates to l[2:5]
 index 3 relates to l[5]
 index 4 relates to l[6]
 index 5 relates to l[7]
 index 6 relates to l[8:11]
```

If I find a group, I need to return the sum of it. I'm thinking it for days and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I have edited. I hope it clarifies the problem.

Comment: this list: l = [1, 1, 1, 0, 2] will result in a proxy like: p[0] = 3, p[1] = 0, p[2] = 2

Comment: l = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5] would be p[0] = 0 , p[1] = 0, p[2] = 4, p[3] = 1, p[4] = 10

Answer (score 0):

You could use `groupby` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def Proxy(l):
    return [sum(g) for _, g in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x or object())]

l = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 6, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0]
print(Proxy(l))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwFET3OcUsE8iirVCK4B26Fylao02b5IdvBD19mi6EDm8xizcwcU8vCtUtcs4Tk4dNhhORW2B9JE6YmdY47EKMZsKdadulU7VACZu0ckC7rF7OChMxHhozbDhW0ml8zN643g9jj63GhmLR8DbPJJXqhHBo0J40CueD0q8aF43qj5/Ticg2JHn8UDl/AQ)):

```
[0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 2, 12, 0, 0]
```